# Insertar datos de una tabla a otra sin duplicados

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo dos tablas en diferentes bases de datos con la misma estructura, en la base de **datos1** llega la información a una de las tablas, la información que llega a esta tabla la tengo que pasar a la tabla de la base de **datos2**.

Tengo el siguiente script que hace esto sin problema no importa las veces que yo lo ejecute el no mete duplicados solo mete los registros que hay en la base de **datos1** y que no hay en la base de **datos2**

```
INSERT INTO [Datos1].dbo.lotesInsert (Codlote,Animal,Peso)
SELECT *
FROM [Datos2].dbo.lotesInsert T1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                     FROM [Datos1].dbo.lotesInsert T2
                    WHERE t2.Codlote = t1.Animal)
```

así quedan los datos cuando ejecuto el script,
los manda a la otra base de datos sin problema,  si inserto en
la base de **datos1** otro animal o sea el siguiente el solo manda ese no me duplica los datos solo manda los que no existen en la base de **datos2**
**"Asi llega la infomacion en la base de datos2"**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando cambio de lote me duplica el lote anterior,  en la imagen vemos que si hay un lote lo inserta bien sin duplicados sin problema, pero inserto el lote **18101**  me duplica el lote **18100**
**"Asi esta en la base de datos1"**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

acá ya ejecute el script con los datos del nuevo lote, el nuevo lote lo inserta bien, pero duplica el anterior
**"así llegan a la base de datos2"**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguna solución para esto he o una explicación de por que pasa y así solucionarlo

Comment: estas igualando t2.Codlote = t1.Animal??? eso esta bien???

Comment: Es que si cambio esto mete todo duplicado o si lo comparo con codlote = codlote no inserta nada

Comment: asi como esta, no tiene sentido.. seria mejor tener un timestamp para saber que hay que agregar.. si no, es medio magico lo que esta haciendo

Comment: ¿Es decir compararlo con un campo de fecha y que vaya insertando los últimos insertados según la fecha?

Comment: seria lo idea... si no, como se que es nuevo y que es viejo?

Comment: Mmmm lo voy a intentar muchas gracias

Comment: Como dice @gbianchi no tiene sentido tal como la tienes, pero lo que deberias hacer es en el exists igualar los campos que son comunes, algo asi: `NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [Datos1].dbo.lotesInsert T2 WHERE T2.Codlote = t1.Codlote AND T2.Animal = t1.Animal)` inclusive podrias igualar los valores de peso para asegurarte que ninguno se duplique

Comment: @gbianchi pero según entiendo esa es la idea que no se dupliquen los datos si ya existen o no?

Comment: @JosueArriola habla de lotes. es todo realmente muy confuso...tu consulta es una mejora bastante considerable..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo básicamente el detalle lo tienes en el `SELECT` (que finalmente es el que "decide" que elementos se tomaran para pasar al `INSERT`; ahora te comento, dado que quieres que no se repita `CodLote` y `Animal` te sugiero el siguiente Query (enfocandome en el `SELECT` para que lo coloques donde ya lo tienes):

```
    SELECT *
    FROM [Datos2].dbo.lotesInsert T1
     WHERE CONCAT(T1.CodLote, '~', CAST(T1.Animal AS VARCHAR(15))) 
           NOT IN 
           (SELECT CONCAT(T2.CodLote, '~',  CAST(T2.Animal AS VARCHAR(15)))
                         FROM [Datos1].dbo.lotesInsert T2)
```

> El caracter `~` es solo un separador que me gusta emplear. Te sugiero dejarlo o colocar uno de tu preferencia.

En caso que necesites no se incluya tambien si coincide `Peso` agrega en ambos CONCAT el separador y el campo **Peso** en las parte de T1 y T2.

Comment: Si usas `CONCAT` no es necesario hacer el `CAST` a `VARCHAR`